# Libgdx: Unable to click buttons or view dialog window when added to a specific scene

Tags: java, libgdx, dialog

**Please note, this is not complete whatsoever its just a basic structure to show how everything is working out.**

I am working on a game; where instead of using different screens, they use scenes instead. See below for the structure of the game code.

How to add in game buttons with current code:

I have to just add images to the sceneTop and check if mouse is within a specific rectangle, if it is do some rendering magic to press button. This is fine for now.

Issue:

I want to add a dialog window but it doesn't work correctly. Not only does it not show the buttons/text of the dialog but when you set the inputProcessor to the stage that contains the dialog, the clicking area is off (I assume this is due to the different scenes being layered). If I add the dialog in the main game class and basically delete the lines rendering the scenes, it works perfectly.

Alternate option:

I instead created a table with a selectBox and added it with batch method. This shows the selectBox, but isn't clickable.

The MenuComponent class is where I want to implement either the dialog or table. Basically I want a popup that has a selectBox in it to change something in game.

```
Main Game: // being initialized in main method of another class that setups the main window
public class Game extends ApplicationAdapter
    public void create () {
        context = new GameContext(this);
        context.create();
    }
    public void render () {
        for (GameScene scene : context.getScenes()) {
            scene.update();
            scene.render();
        }
    }

GameContext class:
    public void create() {
        this.connectScene = new ConnectScene(this); //basically a log in screen
        connectScene.create();
    }
    public void createScenes() { // called when login button is pressed
        this.input = new GameInputProcessor(this); //sets this inputProcessor in a later method
        this.sceneTop = new sceneTop(this);
        sceneTop.create();
        this.sceneBottom= new sceneBottom(this);
        sceneBottom.create();
        //fix crash on server disconnect after dispose has been called
        if(sceneList.size() == 0) {
            sceneList.add(sceneBottom);
            sceneList.add(sceneTop );
        }else {
            sceneList.set(0, sceneBottom);
            sceneList.set(1, sceneTop );
        }
    }

public class GameInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
    public GameInputProcessor(GameContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        for (GameScene scene : context.getScenes()) {
            if (scene.handleClick(screenX, screenY, button)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        for (GameScene scene : context.getScenes()) {
            if (scene.handleClickRelease(screenX, screenY, button)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        float x = Gdx.input.getDeltaX();
        float y = Gdx.input.getDeltaY();
        for (GameScene scene : context.getScenes()) {
            if (scene.handleDrag(screenX, screenY, x, y)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        for (GameScene scene : context.getScenes()) {
            if (scene.handleMouseMove(screenX, screenY)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    }

sceneTop class

public class sceneTop implements GameScene {
    private GameContext context;
    public void create() {
    //does its own create stuff for that specific scene (player stuff)
    mainmenu = new MenuComponent(context);
    }
    public void render(){
    //do other render stuff before with spritebatch
    mainmenu.render();
    }


sceneBottom class

public class sceneBottom implements GameScene {
    private GameContext context;
    public void create() {
    //does its own create stuff for that specific scene (control/inventory stuff)
    }


GameScene class:

public interface GameScene {
    void create();

    void update();

    void render();

    void dispose();

    boolean handleDrag(float screenX, float screenY, float diffX, float diffY);

    boolean handleClick(float x, float y, int button);

    boolean handleMouseMove(float x, float y);

    boolean handleClickRelease(float x, float y, int button);
}

Menu class:
public class MenuComponent extends SceneComponent<sceneTop> implements InputProcessor {
//public abstract class SceneComponent<T extends GameScene> // <--- SceneComponent class
    public void create() {
        Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
        table = new Table();
        orthoCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        selectBox=new SelectBox<String>(skin);
        selectBox.setSize(100, 100);
        selectBox.setPosition(10, 10);
        selectBox.setItems("XYZ","ABC","PQR","LMN");
        table.add(selectBox);
        table.setPosition(300, 100);
        stage.addActor(table);
    }
    public void render(){
        table.draw( batch, 1f );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should look into scene2d.ui package, that should help you a lot.

Comment: @MrStahlfelge How would this help me? I used table as well from package, but the clicking area is completely off.

Comment: It would help you that a lot of code is predefined, known to work.